# Como criar "Banner" com css?

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de produzir um **Banner** semelhante ao da foto usando **css**.

Tentei usando caracteres `UTF-8` e o resultado estava quase perfeito, mas gostaria de fazer com **css** pra evitar alguns problemas de reponsividade.

**HTML**

```
<div style='background-color:black;'>
      <p><span style='float:left; color: white;'>&#9654;</span>
           <span style='color: white'>Texto no interior do banner</span>
          <span style='float:rigth; color:white;'>&#9664;</span>
       </p>
</div>
```

**Resultado**

▶
           Texto no interior do banner
          ◀

Como poderia fazer com **Css** ?

Comment: Esse texto será dinâmico, ou trocado com frequência? Caso não seja, você pode simplificar usando um .png um até mesmo um .gif

Comment: @MicaelFerreira o texto será dinâmico...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

com css é possível definir borders diferentes para criar formas triangulares.

```
<div class="banner">Texto</div>

.banner {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: -25px;
  border-left: 26px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 26px solid blue;
  width: 0;
}

.banner:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: -25px;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 26px solid blue;
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso ai mano ... Beleza !

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uma versão usando dois `linear-gradiente` como `background-image`, assim vc não precisa de `pseudos-elementos` e economiza algumas linhas de código. Caso queira fazer com pseudo-elementos mesmo sugiro que use `transforme:skwe()`

Conceito da ideia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código referente as imagens acima:**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, red);
}


.box {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;

  background-image: 
                    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 20%, black 20%, black 80%, transparent 80%), 
                    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 20%, black 20%, black 80%, transparent 80%);

  background-origin: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 2rem transparent solid;
  border-right: 2rem transparent solid;
  padding: 0px 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Meu Texto</div>
```